Shell command to find common lines in files - with a difference
I'd like to know if/how this can be solved using standard unix commands.
I have two files and want to identify (a) the lines that are common to both files (b) in the first file only and (c) in second file only.
Usually I'd solve this with either cat&uniq, comm or fgrep, however I only want to match common lines on a 1:1 basis i.e. not match 1 line in file 1 to multiple matching lines in file 2.
Consider..
File 1
A
B
C
A
B
C

File 2
A
B
A
D

Expected results..
Common in both: A, B, A
In file 1 only: C, B, C
In file 2 only: D


Assuming the magic 'E' and disappearing 'D' are typos (And assuming you meant 'D' instead of 'E' in the example output.)
Not necessarily in that order, but this works:
awk 'FNR==NR{f1[$0]++; next} {f2[$0]++}
END{
    print "Common in both", ARGV[1], ARGV[2] ":"
    for (e in f1) {
        while (e in f2 && f2[e]>0 && f1[e]>0) {
            print e
            f1[e]--
            f2[e]--
        }
    }
    print "Only in " ARGV[1] ":"
    for (e in f1) 
        while (f1[e]>0) {
            print e
            f1[e]--
        }
    print "Only in " ARGV[2] ":"
    for (e in f2) 
        if (f2[e]>0) {
            print e
            f2[e]--
        }
    }
' file_1 file_2

Prints:
Common in both file_1 file_2:
A
A
B
Only in file_1:
B
C
C
Only in file_2:
D

Or, in Ruby which will maintain order and easy formatting:
ruby -e 'BEGIN{
    f1=Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=0}
    f2=Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=0} 
}

File.foreach(ARGV[0]){ |l| f1[l.chomp]+=1 }
File.foreach(ARGV[1]){ |l| f2[l.chomp]+=1 }

END{
    if (f1.keys & f2.keys)
        print "In #{ARGV[0]} and #{ARGV[1]}: "
            int=[]
            while !(set=(f1.keys & f2.keys)).empty?
                int.concat set
                set.each{|i| 
                    f1[i]>1 ? f1[i]-=1 : f1.delete(i) 
                    f2[i]>1 ? f2[i]-=1 : f2.delete(i) 
                }
            end
        puts int.join(", ")
    end

    if !f1.empty?
        print "#{ARGV[0]} only: "
        e=[]
        while !(f1.empty?)
            e.concat f1.map{|k,v| k}
            f1=f1.select{|k,v| [k,v] if v>1}.map{|k,v| [k,v-1]}.to_h
            end
        puts e.join(", ")
    end
    if !f2.empty?
        print "#{ARGV[1]} only: "
        e=[]
        while !(f2.empty?)
            e.concat f2.map{|k,v| k}
            f2=f2.select{|k,v| [k,v] if v>1}.map{|k,v| [k,v-1]}.to_h
            end
        puts e.join(", ")
    end
}
' file_1 file_2 

Prints:
In file_1 and file_2: A, B, A
file_1 only: B, C, C
file_2 only: D


Thanks for the neat solution (and for spotting - the now corrected - typo!)

You can use awk for that, try:
awk 'BEGIN {print "Common in both:"} FNR==NR {count1[$0]++; next} count1[$0]-- > 0 {print $0}' file1 file2 && \
awk 'BEGIN {print "\nIn file1 only:"} FNR==NR {count2[$0]++; next} count2[$0]-- <= 0 {print $0}' file2 file1 && \
awk 'BEGIN {print "\nIn file2 only:"} FNR==NR {count1[$0]++; next} count1[$0]-- > 0 {print $0 > "/dev/null"; next} {print $0}' file1 file2


BEGIN {}: was added to print titles once ("Common in both", "In file 2 only", "In file1 only")
NR (Number of Records): This is a built-in awk variable that holds the total number of records (i.e., lines) read so far from all files.
FNR (File Number of Records): This is another built-in awk variable that holds the number of records read so far from the current file.

file1:
A
B
C
A
B
C

file2:
A
B
A
D

output:
Common in both:
A
B
A

In file1 only:
C
B
C

In file2 only:
D


Sorry, It returns wrong output for "field2 only", I fixed it, and updated the answer. Should be ok now.
